# String comparison using general comparators

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to see what happens when we compare strings directly using operators like <, >, etc. The two usages in the code below surprisingly give different answers. Aren't they exactly same way of saying things?

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
T max(T a, T b)
{    
  //Usage 1:
  if (a > b) return a; else return b;

  //Usage 2:
  return a > b ? a : b ;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "max(\"Alladin\", \"Jasmine\") = " << max("Alladin", "Jasmine") << std::endl ;
}
```

Usage 1 gives "Jasmine" while usage 2 gives "Alladin".

Comment: Using g++, both cases give me "Alladin".

Comment: How are you compiling it?

Comment: It looks like a compiler issue. I was compiling using http://cpp.sh/. When I use g++, it gives "Alladin" in both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use:

```
max("Alladin", "Jasmine")
```

it is equivalent to using:

```
max<char const*>("Alladin", "Jasmine")
```

In the function, you end up comparing pointers. The outcome of the call will depend on the values of the pointers. It is not guaranteed to be predictable.

Perhaps you want to use:

```
max(std::string("Alladin"), std::string("Jasmine"))
```

or

```
max<std::string>("Alladin", "Jasmine")
```

Be warned that some compiler might pick up `std::max` when you use that. You may want to change `max` to `my_max` or something like that.

Comment: Your first suggestion of typecasting both to std::string is not working. Error: 15:104: error: call of overloaded 'max(std::string, std::string)' is ambiguous. The second suggestion is working very well.

Comment: Working fine with my_max. Since I was not using namespace std, i didn't expect it to pick up std::max. Thanks!

Comment: @SonuKMishra, ADL is the culprit. Look for Argument Dependent Lookup here and the web to understand why that happens.

Comment: No need for `my_max`. The unqualified name `max` is looked up in multiple scopes, `::` and `::std::` (since it's used from `::` and with `::std::string`). If you don't want that lookup, just specify the namespace yourself: `::max<std::string>("a", "b")`.

Answer (score 3):

Both methods are wrong. Character strings don't have valid `>` operator.

You can compare `std::string` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class T>
T my_max(T a, T b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

int main()
{
    std::string a = "Alladin";
    std::string b = "Jasmine";
    std::cout << "my max: " << my_max(a, b) << std::endl;

    //standard max function:
    std::cout << "standard max: " << max(a, b) << std::endl;
}
```

The expected result should always be "Jasmine"

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Error: call of overloaded 'max(std::string&, std::string&)' is ambiguous

Comment: I see it's the same problem pointed out by @RSahu, template function has to be changed to `my_max`

Answer (score 3):

You are not actually comparing the string in your code. `"Alladin"` and `"Jasmine"` are actually of the type `const char[]` and they decay into pointers when you call `max("Alladin", "Jasmine")`.  This means that in your function you are comparing the address of the strings and not the contents.

If you meant to test `std::string`s then you need to create `std::string`s and pass them to your `max` function.